# String Index Error for Binary to Decimal Python Solution

Tags: python

I am coming up with a python code to convert binary to decimal. My first part of the code is to count the length of the digit entered and the second part is to convert it to decimal.

However at line 12 I run into a string index out of range error. May I know how to rectify this? Based on my limited understanding it shouldn't be out of range cause it's within the length of the digit.

Thank you!

```
num=(input("Your binary input please: "))
counter=int(num)
count=0 
total=0
start=0
power=0
while counter!= 0: 
    counter//=10
    count+=1 #the total length of digits 
print(count)
for i in range(count,-1,-1):
    total+=int(num[i])*2**power
    power+=1
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> count = 4
>>> for i in range(count,-1,-1):
...  print(i)
... 
4
3
2
1
0
```

If you've a 4 chars long string, the index goes from 0 to 3. You're starting from 4, num[4] does not exists.

Syntax
range(start, stop, step)

you've to set start to count - 1.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. That solved the problem!